# DTCoreText with Swift 3 issues

Tags: ios, swift, dtcoretext

I was trying to get DTCoreText to change around some simple HTML from JSON. I was trying to implement the simple "Smoke Text" they give in the example but I'm having issues getting the switch around to work. Has anyone used it in swift 3.

I'm not sure if I'm actually using the DTCoreText at this point.

```
func updatethePage(){
    if let items = self.swiftyJsonVar2["daily"]["leadmessage"].string {

        data = items.data(using: .utf8)
        attrString = NSAttributedString(htmlData: data,options:nil, documentAttributes:nil)
        print(attrString)
        self.leadStory.attributedText = attrString!
    }


}
```

I now have it running but the error it is throwing is

```
Optional(This is the lead message
And naother line
{
    CTForegroundColor = "<CGColor 0x600000085c80> [<CGColorSpace 0x6000000348e0> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome; Generic Gray Gamma 2.2 Profile; extended range)] ( 0 1 )";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7f8abb50f270> font-family: \"Times New Roman\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
    NSParagraphStyle = "<CTParagraphStyle: 0x6080000d0840>{base writing direction = -1, alignment = 4, line break mode = 0, default tab interval = 36\nfirst line head indent = 0, head indent = 0, tail indent = 0\nline height multiple = 0, maximum line height = 0, minimum line height = 0\nline spacing adjustment = 0, paragraph spacing = 12, paragraph spacing before = 12\n}";
})
2016-10-06 11:14:56.485 JSONTesting[61040:4582698] -[__NSCFType lineBreakMode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080000d0840
2016-10-06 11:14:57.251 JSONTesting[61040:4582698] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType lineBreakMode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080000d0840'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010876534b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001081c621e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001087d4f34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001086eac15 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001086ea798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIFoundation                        0x0000000110c028bd __NSStringDrawingEngine + 647
    6   UIFoundation                        0x0000000110c0b3d4 -[NSAttributedString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) boundingRectWithSize:options:context:] + 797
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010906eb18 -[UILabel _textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:includingShadow:] + 1199
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010906e42f -[UILabel textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:] + 68
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000109073f53 -[UILabel _intrinsicSizeWithinSize:] + 168
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000109073916 -[UILabel _ensureBaselineMetricsReturningBounds] + 196
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000109073a89 -[UILabel _baselineOffsetFromBottom] + 31
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001090723b4 -[UILabel _baselineOffsetParametersDidChange] + 98
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010906ffc0 -[UILabel _setAttributedText:andTakeOwnership:] + 229
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000109070044 -[UILabel setAttributedText:] + 115
    15  JSONTesting                         0x00000001075de10d _TFC11JSONTesting21importantWPController13updatethePagefT_T_ + 2637
    16  JSONTesting                         0x00000001075dd334 _TFFC11JSONTesting21importantWPController10updatePageFT_T_U_FGV9Alamofire12DataResponseP__T_ + 868
    17  Alamofire                           0x0000000107787f59 _TFFFC9Alamofire11DataRequest8responseuRxS_30DataResponseSerializerProtocolrFT5queueGSqCSo13DispatchQueue_18responseSerializerx17completionHandlerFGVS_12DataResponsewx16SerializedObject_T__DS0_U_FT_T_U_FT_T_ + 889
    18  Alamofire                           0x0000000107787fb7 _TTRGRx9Alamofire30DataResponseSerializerProtocolrXFo___XFdCb___ + 39
    19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010bf78980 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010bfa20cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010bf828d6 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 406
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001087294f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001086eef8d __CFRunLoopRun + 2205
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001086ee494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000110599a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    26  UIKit                               0x0000000108de7f34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    27  JSONTesting                         0x00000001075d577f main + 111
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010bfee68d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: What are those "issues"? Compiler errors? Runtime errors? Wrong results?

Comment: Martin I have updated the answer. DTCoreText is a little cryptic and has a lot of old code laying around....trying to get a handle on its use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to place this into a DTCoreTextViewContent instead of just a normal lablel.